# How to access a Bokeh object by its name in complex layouts

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am building an interface with a complex layout (e.g. multiple rows and columns) and I am trying to figure out a way of simplifying the access to a given object (be it a figure, widget etc) through its name. Let's take the following example:

```py
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
output_notebook()

x = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
y = np.random.randint(1,10,10)

p1 = figure()
p1.line(x,y)
p2 = figure()
p2.line(x,y)
p3 = figure(title='Me!', name='target')
p3.line(x,y)

c = column([p2,p3])
r = row(p1,c)
```

Is there a way to access `p3` from the main layout object `r`? I understand that for the provided example it is possible to use the variable name directly, but my app contains plots that are plotted in sub-functions. I could return the handle of each plot individually, but I was wondering if there was a method to search "multi-dimensional" (i.e. navigating through the children) layouts by properties. I tried using `r.select(name='target')`, but this returns:

```py
TypeError: select() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` method accepts a dict of attributes to their values. In your case, try using `dict(name='target')`.

Comment: Cool, this works but returns:
```r.select(dict(name='target'))
<generator object find.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x100e2cc00>```. Can I access the figure's properties from that? And Can you confirm that `select` will also go down in the hierarchy, i.e. find children of children?

Comment: Generators in Python are lazy collections over which you can iterate. Either use `select_one` (it will throw if there are multiple matching items), or iterate over the result like `for model in r.select(...): ...`, or convert it to a list like `list(r..select(...))`.